# Accessing a boolean field outside of a namespace

Tags: namespaces, initialization, global

I am reading the book of the art of assembly language to learn assembly language. In the topic of namespaces, it is mentioned that to access the names outside of a namespace, we can use e @global: operator. then HLA will use the global definition of that name rather than the local definition (if a local definition even exists).
like this snippet code :

```
type
 integer: int32;
namespace myNames;
 static
 i:@global:integer;
 j:uns32;
 const
 pi:real64 := 3.14159;
end myNames;
```

some part of My program is as follows:

```
program Namespaces_2;

#include("Stdlib.hhf");
type 
    s:string;
    u:uns32;
    r: real64; 
   b: boolean;

type
    works: record
   is_hard: b;
    salary: u ;
    time: r;
    employer: s;
      endrecord;

static
    testwork:works:= works:[true,1000,630.25,"hashem"];//accept the <true> or <false>

namespace teacher;
        type 
          detail_teacher :record
                   degree:@global:s;  
                   university:@global:s;  
                   number_student:@global:u;//only for teachers.  
                       endrecord;
static 
   teacherwork: @global:works:= @global:works:[true,15600,50.63,"mrs.habibi"];//this 
               //line is chalanging me .it does not accept the <<true>> or <<false>>
       teacherpersonal:@global:personality;
       teacherdetail : detail_teacher;
       written_book : @global:s;//only for teachers       
    end  teacher;
begin Namespaces_2;
   //information for a teacher
      mov(true,teacher.teacherwork.is_hard);//this line also accept <true> or <false>
      stdout.put(teacher.teacherwork.is_hard,nl);
       stdout.put(testwork.is_hard);

end Namespaces_2;
```

I get this error when I run this program:

```
Error in file "Namespaces_2.hla" at line 28 [errid:61846/hlaparse.bsn]:
Undefined symbol.
Near: << true >>

HLAPARSE assembly failed with 1 errors
```

If I remove the `is_hard: b;` field in the works record and then line 28 will be:

```
static 
   teacherwork: @global:works:= @global:works:[15600,50.63,"mrs.habibi"]; 
the problem will solve.
//********************* 
    My question is that:
//**********************
```

Why does the compiler not accept initialization in this way (line 28) for this variable, but accepts two other methods in lines 19 and 36?

Am I doing something wrong or is this a compiler error?
I would like to thank anyone who can tell me the reason or guide me in this field.

I think I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know why. I have written more complete explanations in the main text.

Comment: Let's just note that HLA is at some distance from assembly language, and your question goes more to the HL part of HLA (i.e. scoping rules and directives) rather than traditional assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded And  found the trick to fix this problem. because the error is related to not defining << true >> and << false >> in our namespace ,Just put @global prefix before these symbols to eliminate the error.
(For example: @global:true or @global:false for line 28) as follows:

teacherwork: @global:works:= @global:works:[@global:true,1560,50.63,"mrs.habibi"];